# Discovering remote Terminal for Terminal Escape Codes? (DECDHL in this case)

Tags: bash, terminal, ansi-escape, konsole, terminal.app

I am trying to determine WHAT console I am running in. (Exceptionally hard based on the research I have done so far.) The latest feature that I discovered that would be useful is Double High, Double Wide for a couple of scenarios.

The setup is a Kubuntu 15.04 machine with native (lower) and remote access via Terminal.app on OS X 10.10.4.

Based on [vt100.net](http://www.vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/DECDHL) Apple is doing the right thing.

[image]

```
#!/bin/bash

# Cool effect with OS X Terminal.app
# Not as much on others (Like Konsole)
function embiggen()
{
    # Yellow (Darker) foreground
    #                 |       Black backround
    #                 |             |
    printf "\x1b[38;5;226m\x1b[48;5;0m"

    #  Double high 'top anchor'
    #            |       line down
    #            |       |     Start of line
    #            |       |     |
    printf "\x1b#3$1\x1b[B\x1b[G"

    # Yellow (Bright) foreground
    #                 |         Red background
    #                 |    (Bright) |
    printf "\x1b[38;5;229m\x1b[48;5;196m"

    #  Double high 'bottom anchor'
    #            |       line down
    #            |       |     Start of line
    #            |       |     |
    printf "\x1b#4$1\x1b[B\x1b[G\n\n"
}

clear
embiggen "Hello, World"
```

With Konsole

[image]

With Konsole the rendering **seems** to be controlled from bottom to top. i.e. each line is drawn bottom to top basically topmost line wins. However, repaints are less than predictable.

**Is it remotely possible to use some of the extended features in a reasonably gracefully degraded way when the terminal doesn't support extended formating?**

Best 'solution' I have thought of is using a custom entry point with 
`ssh -i ... usr@svr.dom bash --init-file osx_remote -i`

Answer (score 0):

The short answer, is "no" - this is not possible using just escape sequences.

- You cannot tell whether the terminal actually displays double-sized characters.  Using the cursor-position report, you *can* tell (except for buggy implementations) if the terminal used two cells on the screen to represent a double-width character.  xterm did that long ago; other terminals do that.
- Double-sized characters are a VT100 feature, so they are not listed in a device attributes response either.  That would be of limited use, since some terminal emulator developers simply cut/paste responses to make them satisfy applications which check for specific features.

If you were running locally (rather than via ssh), conceivably you could write a program which did an X Window dump and analyzed *that* picture.