# Is there a way to detect the terminal program that someone is using in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, terminal

I'm trying to make a bash script that behaves differently based on the terminal program that someone is using (Putty, mobaxterm, etc). Is there any way to retrieve this kind of information from a bash script?

I was searching around online but I was not able to find anything (or I'm just wording it incorrectly, which could be a distinct possibility).

thank you

Comment: What do you want to do differently for different terminals?

Comment: Yes, tell us what you want to do. Sounds a lot like an XY-Problem - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem .

Comment: There's no reliable way to do this.  A related question was asked in [Discovering remote Terminal for Terminal Escape Codes? (DECDHL in this case)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32019235/discovering-remote-terminal-for-terminal-escape-codes-decdhl-in-this-case).  Agreeing that OP should identify the actual problem to be solved is a first step toward answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that these are terminal *emulators*. There is a simple, crude [identification function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enquiry_character) for (most?) modern line terminals (now that's an oxymoron!) but it will return something like `vt102` or `xterm` i.e. whatever the emulator is emulating; not the identity of the program performing this emulation. Incidentally, this is usually used when the session is initiated, and reflected in the value of the `$TERM` environment variable.

Comment: ...and as a rule, the information is incorrect (VTE-based terminals claim functionality which they do not implement, other terminals such as Konsole under-report the feature).  Likewise, `TERM` is largely meaningless.

Comment: One notable exception to ENQ is the Sun console.  It lacks the feature altogether.

Comment: For other examples, the source-code for [qterm](http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Misc/qterm-6.0.3/man.html) would be useful to read.

Comment: On the other hand, `ENQ` is used rarely with Linux.  It used to be useful in combination with `tset`, but I've not seen any (non-museum) uses within the past 10-15 years.

Answer (score 0):

The common way to do this is the environment variable `TERM`. Try

```
echo $TERM
```

That should output the terminal emulator's type, indicating its capabilities. Often, though not always, the value of `TERM` will be the name of the terminal emulator. For example, [xterm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm) may set TERM to `xterm`, or to `xterm-color`, depending on configuration.

Note that the user can change this variable, so it *may* contain something completely different.

That said, if you want to do fancy things with the terminal from a script, you don't need to build support for different terminals by hand. There are various libraries that offer all the usual functions (clear terminal, resize window, change font etc.). The most popular one is [terminfo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminfo); there are various packages that build on terminfo.

Comment: `TERM` is not the terminal emulator's name, but instead is the name for a set of features which are supposed to match a given terminal.

Comment: @ThomasDickey: Yes, thanks for pointing it out (though often the "name for the set of features" happens to be the terminal name, e.g. "xterm"). Edited answer.

Comment: There are a dozen or more entries for xterm (see [link](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/terminfo.html)), which all differ (according to given configurations).

Comment: @ThomasDickey: Thanks for the list. And I just realized who you are - you should probably have answered yourself, you certainly know a lot more about terminfo and xterm than I do :-).

Comment: It's awkward, when there are two answers asserting it's possible, and the OP has not clarified what's wanted.  I may followup if OP provides useful information.